# Python | Selenium Issue with scrolling down and find by class name

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

For one study research I would like to scrape some links from webpages which located out of viewport (to see this links you need to scroll down the page).

- Page example (https://www.twitch.tv/lirik)
- Link example: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09FVR22R2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09FVR22R2)
- Link located in div class='`Layout-sc-nxg1ff-0 itdjvg default-panel`' (in total 16 links on the page).

I have write the script but I get empty list:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.twitch.tv/lirik')

time.sleep(3)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")

time.sleep(3)

panel_blocks = browser.find_elements(by='class name', value='Layout-sc-nxg1ff-0 itdjvg default-panel')
browser.close()
print(panel_blocks)
print(type(panel_blocks))
```

I just get empty list after page was loaded. Here is output from the script above:

```
/usr/local/bin/python /Users/greg.fetisov/PycharmProjects/baltazar_platform/Twitch_parser.py
[]
<class 'list'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

p.s.
when webdriver opens the page, I see there is no scroll down action. It just open a page and then close it after time.sleep cooldown.

**How I can change the script to get the links properly?**

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the values of the *href* attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/lirik")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.Layout-sc-nxg1ff-0.itdjvg.default-panel > a")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09FVR22R2', 'http://bs.serving-sys.com/Serving/adServer.bs?cn=trd&pli=1077437714&gdpr=$%7BGDPR%7D&gdpr_consent=$%7BGDPR_CONSENT_68%7D&adid=1085757156&ord=[timestamp]', 'https://store.epicgames.com/lirik/rumbleverse', 'https://bitly/3GP0cM0', 'https://lirik.com/', 'https://streamlabs.com/lirik', 'https://twitch.amazon.com/tp', 'https://www.twitch.tv/subs/lirik', 'https://www.youtube.com/lirik?sub_confirmation=1', 'http://www.twitter.com/lirik', 'http://www.instagram.com/lirik', 'http://gfuel.ly/lirik', 'http://www.cyberpowerpc.com/', 'https://www.cyberpowerpc.com/page/Intel/LIRIK/', 'https://discord.gg/lirik', 'http://www.amazon.com/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&linkCode=ur2&tag=l0e6d-20&linkId=YNM2SXSSG3KWGYZ7']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using a wrong locator.
2. You should use expected conditions explicit waits instead of hardcoded pauses.
3. `find_elements` method returns a list of web elements while you want to the link inside the element(s).

This should work better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.twitch.tv/lirik')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='channel-panels-container']//a")))
time.sleep(0.5)

link_blocks = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='channel-panels-container']//a")
for link_block in link_blocks:
    link = link_block.get_attribute("href")
    print(link)

browser.close()
```

Comment: thanks for idea, but it doesnt work - got error on loop line (for link_block in link_blocks) - says link_blocks is not iterable..

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It should be `find_elements_by_xpath` there, not `find_element_by_xpath`.